# Pandas fuzzy match merge while deleting rows by index after iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. Each contains 1 word per row. They are pretty close, but there are misspellings and sometimes one df has one or two words the other doesn't.

As a rule, I want to combine df2.word with df1.metadata. If df2.word and df1.word match, are close in spelling, or are close enough and within 1 row from each other, I want to join df2.word with df1.metadata. If there is no close match directly or within 1 row, I want to drop this row.

*However, for efficiency, as I iterate through df1.word looking for a df2.word match, I want to remove matched words from df1 the search space.*

I have:

```html
df1

word      metadata    metadata2

okay        1           A
I           1           A
win         1           A
tree        1           A
apples      1           A
also        0           B
I           0           B
would       0           B
like        0           B
for         0           B 
uh          0           B
oranges     0           B

df2

word

OK.         
I          
want        
three       
apples.     
Also,        
I           
would       
like          
four        
oranges.
```

@manwithfewneeds (thanks!) provided this awesome code (below).

```html
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor


def get_match(word):
    match, score, _ = process.extractOne(word, df1['word'])
    if score > 50:
        s = df1.loc[df1['word'].eq(match), 'metadata'].iloc[0]
        return [word, s]

def main():
    ##swap out ThreadPoolExecutor with ProcessPoolExecutor to switch from
    ##multithreading to multiprocessing
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(get_match, df2['word'])
        return (r for r in results if r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(main(), columns=['word', 'metadata'])
    print(df)
```

This code results in :

```
word      metadata    metadata2

OK.         1           A
I           1           A
want        1           A
three       1           A
apples.     1           A
Also,       0           B  
I           1           A 
would       0           B
like        0           B
four        0           B
oranges.    0           B
```

This is not exactly what I want because you'll notice the second 'I' gets matched with the first 'I' found in df1. This results in the wrong metadata being attached to the second 'I' in df2.

What I want is:

```
word      metadata    metadata2

OK.         1           B
I           1           B
want        1           B
three       1           B
apples.     1           B
Also,       0           B  
I           0           B 
would       0           B
like        0           B
four        0           B
oranges.    0           B
```

I figured I would turn this into a new post as it describes a new problem. Thank you.